# Div flowing outside of container - is it possible?

Tags: html, css

So I'm using a responsive framework called skeleton which works great, however, with a section such as the header and footer, I want the background to span 100% width of the page which is now a popular design choice.

Does anyone have a workaround for this just to make a div pop outside of the container?

Comment: [show us some code you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the container has the default position property (static), you could give the header a `position:absolute`. Then set `top:0`, `left:0` and `right:0`.

Make sure to set the top margin or padding of the container to the same height defined for the header.

This will not work if the container has been given a position value of relative, absolute, or fixed.

Comment: The container is indeed position relative.

Comment: If that is the case, I do not know how else you can accomplish this nicely. You could apply a huge negative left and right margin and offset it with a equally huge positive padding, but that will add scroll bars where the right margin extends past the browser viewport. This less than desirable hack will work only if the container has overflow set to visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
font-size: 0.875em;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
.header-container {
background-color: #CCCCCC;
float: left;
height: 100px;
margin-left: -400px;
overflow: hidden;
padding-right: 800px;
width: 100%;
}
#header {
margin-left: 409px;
margin-top: 10px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I should have said - with the grid system, everything needs to be inside the container - my test page is http://notfilc.eu/ where you can see the grey border around the header was my (failed) attempt.

Comment: Ok, I added some css above, give that a try.

Comment: Thanks, it works well for full screen but starts getting funky when going down to mobile sizes. I guess I could just have header and footer outside of the container, but it seems like it wouldn't be a particularly semantic way to do it.

Comment: That would be the best option and setting the width to 100%. It works really well on mobile when switching from portrait to landscape.

Answer (score 0):

skeleton.css line 301:

```
.container:after {
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This declaration will make sure that any content displayed after the container is not visible, therefore not disrupting the grid in any way on the page.

The container is also set to 960px wide and `position:relative` (skeleton.css line 24)which means that you can't create anything inside the container div that can be set to page width without using javascript ( + jquery for simplicity ). On such a key design feature on most sites it wouldnt be such a great idea to rely on this.

I would try removing the :after declaration on .container and then add a new `<div>` underneath with `width:100%; height:128px;` and see how it affects your grid as a starting point.